# Why is DELETE TOP without ORDER BY allowed?

Tags: t-sql

Why is DELETE TOP without ORDER BY allowed?
Why is DELETE TOP with ORDER BY not allowed?

Doesn't it go against that there is not supposed to be a "natural" order of rows in SQL?

The workaround is

```sql
DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN (
  SELECT TOP n id FROM table WHERE ... ORDER BY ...)
```

Similar quiestion, for UPDATE TOP (n) , ORDER BY is not allowed. Why?

Comment: You can add `SELECT TOP` to the list. This doesn't mean there's any kind of order. The server is free to return the data in the cheapest way possible and `TOP` applies to these results. In other databases you can use `LIMIT` or `FETCH FIRST` without an `ORDER BY` as well.

Comment: `TOP` is allowed without an `ORDER BY` (in most places); it has nothing to do with the fact you are using `DELETE`. As for your point about "natural order", there is no natural order. Without an `ORDER BY` SQL Server will simply process the rows in an arbitrary order.

Comment: The main usage for a `TOP` in a DML statement (like an `UPDATE`/`DELETE`) is when you're batching, in such cases it's actually unlikely that ordering the data matters, as it's the `WHERE` that is going to be filtering the data to the rows you want to effect. If you arbitrarily `UPDATE` 1 million rows in each iteration doesn't change the end goal that all the applicable rows will be `UPDATE`d; what order those rows are `UPDATE`d is inconsequential.

Answer (score 1):

**Why not:** Because it wouldn't make sense except in a very special case. `DELETE` or `UPDATE` produce no results. `ORDER BY` and `TOP` only make sense in batching scenarios. The job of selecting rows for whatever reason is the job of `SELECT`. In ANSI SQL the job of selecting a batch of rows to DELETE is the job of a SELECT subquery

SQL Server's `DELETE TOP` or MySQL's `DELETE ... LIMIT` are extensions. PostgreSQL doesn't allow LIMIT or `FETCH FIRST` in `DELETE`.

This doesn't mean there's any kind of order. The server is free to return the data in the cheapest way possible and `TOP` applies to these results. The order can change if the server decides to parallelize the query or use different join strategies.

In other databases you can use `LIMIT` or `FETCH FIRST` without an `ORDER BY` as well. `LIMIT`, `FETCH FIRST` or `TOP` aren't part of the `ORDER BY` clause

In [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) `LIMIT` can be applied without an `ORDER BY`. From the doc examples:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5;     # Retrieve first 5 rows
```

[PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT) allows both LIMIT and the ANSI SQL `FETCH FIRST`, eg:

```
SELECT * FROM foo FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

As for the why, UPDATE and DELETE produce no results so an `ORDER BY` would make no sense.